# Execute KNIME workflow with python in jupyter lab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-analysis, knime, exploratory-data-analysis

I am trying to execute a simple Knime workflow with python in jupyter lab and also looking to pass the filename for the Knime workflow through python and to get the output on the jupyter lab

I am able to get the knime workflow with knime.Workflow(workflow_path=workflow,workspace_path=workspace).
But it seems that data_table_inputs and data_table_outputs work with training models only. In my below workflow screenshot, there is no training/container node, it's a very simple workflow which takes input file with reader node and applies some filters and generate the statistics. And I want to execute this workflow by passing filename from python code and generate the output on jupyter lab.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import knime
knime.executable_path='/Applications/KNIME 5.1.1.app/Contents/MacOS/Knime'
workspace='/knimedir/knime-workspace'
workflow='testworflow'
knime.Workflow(workflow_path=workflow,workspace_path=workspace)

df=pd.read_csv("/knimedir/bankds.csv")

with knime.Workflow(workflow_path=workflow,workspace_path=workspace) as wf:
    wf.data_table_inputs[0]=df
    wf.execute()
wf.data_table_outputs[0]
```

[testworflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqB7c.png)

Comment: You don't specify what you have done to make this possible or not? For example [here](https://www.knime.com/blog/knime-and-jupyter), which you fail to reference even though it looks like you take a picture from it, says you need to install something. Did you do that? And then you aren't putting what happens when you run this code? Does it error and where? Include the text of any error as a fenced code block here. What have you checked? Does the path `knime.executable_path` work since it has spaces, does Knime not have an extension, etc.?